# How add properties in a React Component in order to be used as "children.property" in a layout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with ReactJS and NextJS. I have built a layout. Now I would use this layout to receive some texts from exported children properties. In my layout.js file the pages are passed as children as following:

```
export default ({children, title = 'title' }) => {  
<div> {children} </div>
}
```

I would use the properties space to pass some text as I have said, to illustrate my think:

```
export default ({children, title = 'title' }) => {  
<p> {children.props.someText} </p> // some properties has been added to the children before export it. 
                                   // I use now theses properties to make some custom processing. 
<div> {children} </div>
}
```

But when I use my React.Component to pass some properties it fails. I use the following method:

```
render() {
return (
 <div someText={textObject}>
     Hello Home

</div> ) }
```

the children.attribute property doesn't appear on my console.log(children).

I have try React.CloneElement but it fails.

So how to do that ? Any hint would be great.

Comment: Component's children are available at `this.props.children`

Comment: I think I have misspelled my request, in fact, I would use this layout to receive some texts from exported children properties.